# Having Issue On Loading Array Items Into jQuery DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Can you please take a look at **[This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/7nd22y0x/)** and let me know why I am not able to load the data from the array into the DataTable instance correctly?

Here is the code which I have:

```
var data =  [ "Dai Rios", "Personnel Lead", "Edinburgh", "2290", "2012/09/26", "$217,500" ];
var tbl = $('#example').DataTable();
$("#load").on("click", function(){
     tbl.rows.add(data).draw();
});
```

Comment: can we see your html as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of "rows" in `tbl.rows.add(data).draw();` use "row" i.e.

instead of

```
tbl.rows.add(data).draw();
```

use

```
tbl.row.add(data).draw();
```

Answer (score 2):

There is slight mistake in you script

```
$("#load").on("click", function(){
  tbl.row.add(data).draw();

});
```

you had it `rows` instead of `row`.